# How to make JMS onMessage method asynchronous

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, message-queue, spring-jms

I am working on a JMS POC which listens to one IBM MQ. The `MQConnectionFactory` has been used for connection with MQ and used `onMessage()` method to listen for input messages. After receiving the message it is being converted to desired object type using `MarshallingMessageConverter` and after some more action it is being pushed to another queue (response).

So far it is working good. However, it seems all the messages in queue are consumed synchronously e.g. 2nd message is entering `onMessage()` method only after the processing of 1st message is complete.

Q1. How can i make it asynchronous in order to improve the performance?

Q2. Is it advised to make it asynchronous?

Below is the snippet of my code:

config.xml:

```xml
<bean id="oxmMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMapper" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMapper" />
    <property name="targetType">
        <util:constant
            static-field="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType.TEXT" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsResponseSenderA" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsMQConnectionFactoryA" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="jmsResponseQueue" />
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="oxmMessageConverter" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsMQConnectionFactoryA" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="transportType">
        <util:constant
            static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT" />
    </property>
    <property name="clientReconnectOptions">
        <util:constant
            static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.CommonConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR" />
    </property>
    <property name="queueManager" value="${queue.manager.A}" />
    <property name="CCDTURL" value="${ccdt.url}"></property>
            
</bean>
```

Listener Class:

```java
public class ListenerServiceImpl implements MessageListener {
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
     // action1
     // action2
     // action3
    jmsResponseSender.convertAndSend(response);
  }
}
```

Comment: onMessage is invoked once per message.You can look at deploying multiple consumers so that messages can be consumed for an improved performance.

Comment: Is there any way to make it asynchronous ? Also when you say multiple consumers , you mean reading message from multiple queue ?

Comment: When Shashi say 'multiple consumers' he means from the same queue, i.e. making them process the queue concurrently. You ask to make it 'asynchronous', but on Message is already asynchronous. What your question appears to be requesting is concurrency. If that's not what you mean, perhaps you could elaborate on what 'asynchronous' means to you in this context?

Comment: Where is your listener configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The `onMessage()` method of a JMS `MessageListener` implementation is *already* asynchronous. Your problem is that you only have 1 `MessageConsumer`. You need to configure multiple consumers so they can consume messages concurrently each using their own `MessageListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `spring-jms`. If you are also using `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter`, then you can configure connection pooling. The properties that you can set can be found in https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring

For your case, say you want a pool of 5 connections:

```
ibm.mq.pool.enabled=true
ibm.mq.pool.maxConnections=5
```

When you do have pooling you will need to make sure that your `onMessage` method is reentrant compliant. In my test I had a `@JmsListener` with concurrency set, and sleeps so I could see the parallel processing.

```java
    @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name}", concurrency = "3-5") 
    public void receiveString(String comment) {
        String fid = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(99));

        logger.info(fid);
        logger.info(fid + " ========================================");
        logger.info(fid + " Received string message is: " + comment);

        logger.info(fid + " Sleeping");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        logger.info(fid + " Waking" );

        logger.info(fid + " ========================================");
    }
```